# Spring Batch Proxy Failure java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy20 cannot be cast to

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, proxy-classes

Why would I be getting a cast error from a proxy based on a bean that is properly implementing an interface? Package and object names have been changed to protect proprietary data.

I know the error

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy20 cannot be cast to package.Order
```

normally comes up when one is not implementing an interface as is expected. In this case I am implementing interfaces for facilitating Proxy generation.

My specific problem is using a collection of domain objects in an enhanced for loop within an ItemWriter implementation. This exception is being thrown from the enhanced for loop I reference below.

```
public void write(List<? extends Order> items) throws Exception {
        for ( Order order : items){
```

Order is an interface implemented by OrderBean.

```
public class OrderBean implements Order
```

And is declared as a Prototype for use by a BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper in a Spring Java Configuration class. As below.

```
@Bean
@Scope("prototype")
public Order order()
```

As an experiment I commented out the Java Configuration declaration, and replaced it with the XML declaration below.

```
<bean name="order"
        scope="prototype"
        class="package.OrderBean"/>
```

The entirety of my configuration appears below as requested in comments. I am not sure why the Order objects are being proxied, unless possibly it comes from the BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper.

Upon further testing, I found I get the same error from any bean set with the Step scope, as in @Scope("step").

```
@Configuration
public class OrderProcessingBatchConfiguration {

    @Value("${batch.jdbc.driver}")
    private String driverClassName;

    @Value("${batch.jdbc.url}")
    private String driverUrl;

    @Value("${batch.jdbc.user}")
    private String driverUsername;

    @Value("${batch.jdbc.password}")
    private String driverPassword;

    @Value("${order.delimiter}")
    private String delimiter;

    @Value("${order.item.field.names}")
    private String[] orderItemFieldNames;

    @Value("${order.item.file.path}")
    private String orderItemFilePath;

    @Value("${order.field.names}")
    private String[] orderFieldNames;

    @Value("${order.file.path}")
    private String orderFilePath;

    @Value("${query.order.clear}")
    private String deleteOrderQuery;

    @Value("${query.order.item.clear}")
    private String deleteOrderItemQuery;

    @Value("${ftp.host.name}")
    private String ftpHostName;

    @Value("${ftp.host.port}")
    private Integer ftpHostPort;

    @Value("${ftp.client.mode}")
    private Integer ftpClientMode;

    @Value("${ftp.file.type}")
    private Integer ftpFileType;

    @Value("${ftp.host.username}")
    private String ftpUsername;

    @Value("${ftp.host.password}")
    private String ftpPassword;

    @Value("${ftp.tasklet.retryIfNotFound}")
    private Boolean retryIfNotFound;

    @Value("${ftp.tasklet.download.attempts}")
    private Integer downloadAttempts;

    @Value("${ftp.tasklet.retry.interval}")
    private Integer retryInterval;

    @Value("${ftp.tasklet.file.name.pattern}")
    private String fileNamePattern;

    @Value("${ftp.host.remote.directory}")
    private String remoteDirectory;

    @Value("${ftp.client.local.directory}")
    private File localDirectory;

    @Value("${ftp.tasklet.sftp}")
    private Boolean sftp;

    @Value("${query.order.insert}")
    private String orderInsertQuery;

    @Value("${query.order.items.insert}")
    private String orderItemInsertQuery;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("jobRepository")
    private JobRepository jobRepository;


    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(driverClassName);
        dataSource.setUrl(driverUrl);
        dataSource.setUsername(driverUsername);
        dataSource.setPassword(driverPassword);

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public SimpleJobLauncher jobLauncher() {
        SimpleJobLauncher jobLauncher = new SimpleJobLauncher();
        jobLauncher.setJobRepository(jobRepository);

        return jobLauncher;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        return new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource());
    }

    @Bean
    @Scope("prototype")
    public OrderItem orderItem(){
        return new OrderItemBean();
    }

    @Bean
    @Scope("prototype")
    public Order order(){
        return new OrderBean();
    }

    @Bean
    //@Scope("step")
    public DelimitedLineTokenizer orderItemLineTokenizer(){
        DelimitedLineTokenizer lineTokenizer = new DelimitedLineTokenizer(delimiter);
        lineTokenizer.setNames(orderItemFieldNames);

        return lineTokenizer;
    }

    @Bean
    //@Scope("step")
    public BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<OrderItem> orderItemFieldSetMapper(){
        BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<OrderItem> orderItemFieldSetMapper = new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<OrderItem>();
        orderItemFieldSetMapper.setPrototypeBeanName("orderItem");

        return orderItemFieldSetMapper;
    }

    @Bean
    //@Scope("step")
    public DefaultLineMapper<OrderItem> orderItemLineMapper(){
        DefaultLineMapper<OrderItem> orderItemLineMapper = new DefaultLineMapper<OrderItem>();
        orderItemLineMapper.setLineTokenizer(orderItemLineTokenizer());
        orderItemLineMapper.setFieldSetMapper(orderItemFieldSetMapper());

        return orderItemLineMapper;
    }

    @Bean
    //@Scope("step")
    public Resource orderItemResource(){
        Resource orderItemResource = new FileSystemResource(orderItemFilePath);

        return orderItemResource;
    }

    @Bean
    //@Scope("step")
    public FlatFileItemReader<OrderItem> orderItemItemReader(){
        FlatFileItemReader<OrderItem> orderItemItemReader = new FlatFileItemReader<OrderItem>();
        orderItemItemReader.setLineMapper(orderItemLineMapper());
        orderItemItemReader.setResource(orderItemResource());

        return orderItemItemReader;
    }

    @Bean
    //@Scope("step")
    public DelimitedLineTokenizer orderLineTokenizer(){
        DelimitedLineTokenizer lineTokenizer = new DelimitedLineTokenizer(delimiter);
        lineTokenizer.setNames(orderFieldNames);

        return lineTokenizer;
    }

    @Bean
    //@Scope("step")
    public BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<Order> orderFieldSetMapper(){
        BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<Order> orderItemFieldSetMapper = new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<Order>();
        orderItemFieldSetMapper.setPrototypeBeanName("order");

        return orderItemFieldSetMapper;
    }

    @Bean
    //@Scope("step")
    public DefaultLineMapper<Order> orderLineMapper(){
        DefaultLineMapper<Order> orderItemLineMapper = new DefaultLineMapper<Order>();
        orderItemLineMapper.setLineTokenizer(orderLineTokenizer());
        orderItemLineMapper.setFieldSetMapper(orderFieldSetMapper());

        return orderItemLineMapper;
    }

    @Bean
    //@Scope("step")
    public Resource orderResource(){
        Resource orderItemResource = new FileSystemResource(orderFilePath);

        return orderItemResource;
    }

    @Bean
    //@Scope("step")
    public FlatFileItemReader<Order> orderItemReader(){
        FlatFileItemReader<Order> orderItemItemReader = new FlatFileItemReader<Order>();
        orderItemItemReader.setLineMapper(orderLineMapper());
        orderItemItemReader.setResource(orderResource());

        return orderItemItemReader;
    }

    @Bean
    @Scope("step")
    public Map<String, Order> orderCache(){
        Map<String, Order> orderCache = new HashMap<String, Order>();

        return orderCache;
    }

    @Bean
    public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate(){
        return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource());
    }

    @Bean
    //@Scope("step")
    public AggregatingFlatFileOrderItemReader aggregatingFlatFileOrderItemReader(){
        AggregatingFlatFileOrderItemReader aggregatingFlatFileOrderItemReader = new AggregatingFlatFileOrderItemReader();
        aggregatingFlatFileOrderItemReader.setJdbcTemplate(jdbcTemplate());
        aggregatingFlatFileOrderItemReader.setOrderCache(orderCache());
        aggregatingFlatFileOrderItemReader.setOrderItemFlatFileItemReader(orderItemItemReader());
        aggregatingFlatFileOrderItemReader.setOrderFlatFileItemReader(orderItemReader());
        aggregatingFlatFileOrderItemReader.setDeleteOrderQuery(deleteOrderQuery);
        aggregatingFlatFileOrderItemReader.setDeleteOrderItemQuery(deleteOrderItemQuery);

        return aggregatingFlatFileOrderItemReader;
    }

    @Bean
    @Scope("step")
    public SessionFactory ftpSessionFactory(){
        DefaultFtpSessionFactory ftpSessionFactory = new DefaultFtpSessionFactory();
        ftpSessionFactory.setHost(ftpHostName);
        ftpSessionFactory.setClientMode(ftpClientMode);
        ftpSessionFactory.setFileType(ftpFileType);
        ftpSessionFactory.setPort(ftpHostPort);
        ftpSessionFactory.setUsername(ftpUsername);
        ftpSessionFactory.setPassword(ftpPassword);

        return ftpSessionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    @Scope(value="step")
    public FtpGetRemoteFilesTasklet myFtpGetRemoteFilesTasklet(){
        FtpGetRemoteFilesTasklet  ftpTasklet = new FtpGetRemoteFilesTasklet();
        ftpTasklet.setRetryIfNotFound(retryIfNotFound);
        ftpTasklet.setDownloadFileAttempts(downloadAttempts);
        ftpTasklet.setRetryIntervalMilliseconds(retryInterval);
        ftpTasklet.setFileNamePattern(fileNamePattern);
        ftpTasklet.setRemoteDirectory(remoteDirectory);
        ftpTasklet.setLocalDirectory(localDirectory);
        ftpTasklet.setSessionFactory(ftpSessionFactory());
        ftpTasklet.setSftp(sftp);

        return ftpTasklet;
    }

    @Bean
    @Scope(value="step")
    public OrderItemWriter orderItemWriter(){
        OrderItemWriter orderItemWriter = new OrderItemWriter();

        orderItemWriter.setJdbcTemplate(jdbcTemplate());
        orderItemWriter.setOrderInsertQuery(orderInsertQuery);
        orderItemWriter.setOrderItemInsertQuery(orderItemInsertQuery);

        return orderItemWriter;
    }
```

Comment: `com.sun.proxy.$Proxy20 cannot be cast to`... to what? How do you connect this `public Order order()` method with the `public void write(List<? extends Order> items)` method?

Comment: Because that is where the exception is being thrown from, the stack trace references the line including the enhanced for loop within the write method. I edited my question to include this information.

Comment: The public Order order() is a Bean declaration using Spring Java Configuration.

Comment: Can you share the rest of your configuration?  I'm not clear as to why Order is being proxied in the first place...

Comment: I posted my complete configuration. I also have no idea why that bean is being proxied. I haven't done anything that should be generating a proxy; as far as I know.

Comment: Did you found any solution for this problem?